# JBoss 4.0 HotDeploy

Tags: jboss

good day.
I am trying to enable hot deploy on my JBoss 4.0.
I have tried to access to localhost:9990, but it doesn't work.
Is there any alternative way to enable it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try localhost:8080/admin-console/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss 4.0 contradicts to port 9990.
The port 9990 is the management console access for JBossAS7 and WildFly.
JBoss 4.0 might have a JMX console which is accessible via 8080.
You can simpel use localhost:8080 and navigate from the welcome page.

Note that hot deploy is not recommended for productional JBossAS4/5 instances because of class loading issues, OOM errors.
You might use it for development.

Also JBossAS4 does not have managed deployments, simple drop the file to server/yourProfile/deploy and it will be picked up and deployed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try it out